# Using Cython to wrap a c++ template to accept any numpy array

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, cython

I'm trying to wrap a parallel sort written in c++ as a template, to use it with numpy arrays of any numeric type. I'm trying to use Cython to do this.

My problem is that I don't know how to pass a pointer to the numpy array data (of a correct type) to a c++ template. I believe I should use fused dtypes for this, but I don't quite understand how.

The code in .pyx file is below

```
# importing c++ template
cdef extern from "test.cpp":
    void inPlaceParallelSort[T](T* arrayPointer,int arrayLength)

def sortNumpyArray(np.ndarray a):
    # This obviously will not work, but I don't know how to make it work. 
    inPlaceParallelSort(a.data, len(a))
```

In the past I did similar tasks with ugly for-loops over all possible dtypes, but I believe there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you want to use a fused type to have Cython call the sorting template for the appropriate specialization of the template.
Here's a working example for all non-complex data types that does this with `std::sort`.

```
# cython: wraparound = False
# cython: boundscheck = False

cimport cython

cdef extern from "<algorithm>" namespace "std":
    cdef void sort[T](T first, T last) nogil

ctypedef fused real:
    cython.char
    cython.uchar
    cython.short
    cython.ushort
    cython.int
    cython.uint
    cython.long
    cython.ulong
    cython.longlong
    cython.ulonglong
    cython.float
    cython.double

cpdef void npy_sort(real[:] a) nogil:
    sort(&a[0], &a[a.shape[0]-1])
```

Comment: This did not compile as is,  the compiler complained a lot about nogil. I had to kill it, but parallelization worked without it.

Comment: @MaximImakaev Yep, the nogil is really only necessary if you want to call the Cython function inside a parallel loop. The parallization inside your sorting function should be fine without it. It's odd that it wouldn't compile with it there though. There's probably some difference in Cython versions. I have a recent development version (pretty similar to 0.22) and it worked fine for me.