# How to take advantage of C++ templates in Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have a C++ library that is templatized - for example a function can be passed as parameter a pointer of floats or integers.
I am calling this using a Cython code where the pointers have been declared using  memory view:

```
numpy.ndarray[float, ndim=3, mode="c"] A

numpy.ndarray[int, ndim=3, mode="c"] B
```

I am currently writing two functions in my `.pyx` file to take care of the two types. I looked up single dispatch generic functions and Fused Types but I could not get them to work on `numpy.ndarray`. Specifically I got invalid syntax error. Is there a way to do "templates" in cython? Thanks! Also as an extension (?) if the `ndarray` was 2 dim instead of 3 dim could the same function take care of it?

Comment: The number of dimensions should be fixed for each function. The solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638094/using-cython-to-wrap-a-c-template-to-accept-any-numpy-array/28651984#28651984 should work for dispatching between types.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem, but now I have a different problem. When I declare the template function (not class) in my pyx file I am getting "its not a type identifier" error in compiling. My C template function is template<class iT, class oT> void normalise(iT *x, oT *y). How do i extern define in pyx file? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to use square braces, not angled braces when declaring the template at the Cython level. That's the Cython syntax. Angled braces are used for typecasts.